# posting similar phonegap apps on google play

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I have a simple 2 page phonegap application where the users can discuss and review about a particular game.
It has ajax calls and stores everything in a common database table on server.

So i can create say 5-6 apps for different games the app code would be almost exactly be the  same just the game type string would have a different value.

Creating such type of apps, does it voilate google plays repititve content policy.
Does google come to know about this as the apps are not native ones, do they scan the html javascript code as well to check if all the code is same?

please help i dont want to get banned from google play

Comment: `i can create say 5-6 apps for different games` why not just create one app that handles discussions and reviews for multiple games?

Comment: it would be good to have a dedicated app (kind of a forum or a walkthrough) for a game, as i use images and some backgrounds of those games, but their names are same in the code in all the apps

Comment: I guess I still don't understand why you need multiple applications - are you just trying to get additional exposure?

Comment: yes...exposure is one of the reason

Comment: `exposure is one of the reason` Yes, that violates Google's developer policies. See here - http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html - "Do not post repetitive content."

Comment: thanks admdrew...that solves my doubt